# Add a character to a string

Tags: python, string, character

I am newbie with python and I have one problem with a small script I hope someone can give me a clue.

I have a file called "one.txt" which has the following 2 lines:

```
Hello
Goodbye
```

I want to add two characters ("/1") to the end of each line and write it in another file called result.txt:

result.txt

```
Hello1/
Goodbye1/
```

I tried the following:

```
x=open("one.txt","r")
y=open("result.txt","w")

for line in x:
    line2= "/1" +line
    y.write(line2)
```

and I get:

```
1/Hello
1/Goodbye
```

if I change line2 with:

```
line2= line + "/1"
```

I get:

```
Hello
/1Goodbye  
/1
```

which is also not correct

any clues?

Comment: It looks like you're going to need to parse the lines to get ahead of the newline character before you add your /1.  Then add your newline character back.

Comment: Does it really write `1/Hello` rather than `/1Hello`?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to strip the newline after reading the line and to add it back in before writing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another version, using context managers for the files (so you don't forget to close them later) - otherwise it's similar to the answer by @IgorPomaranskiy:

```
with open("one.txt") as x, open("result.txt", "w") as y:
    for line in x:
        y.write("{}\n".format(line.strip() + "/1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = open("one.txt", "r")
y = open("result.txt", "w")

for line in x:
    y.write("{}/1\n".format(line.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you read a line from a file, the string contains the newline character that indicated the end of the line. Your string isn't `"Hello"`, it's `"Hello\n"`. You need to remove that newline, create your output string, and add another newline when you write it back out.

```
for line in x:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    line2 = line + '/1\n'
    y.write(line2)
```